# How to write clean code when creating new Obj from existing one with value modifications in JS?

Tags: javascript, object

Summary: my attempt is to take this `firstObj` object and create a new object `secondObj` that has changed values and to use the cleanest code possible.

```js
const firstObj = {
  one: '100px',
  two: '200px',
}

const secondObj = {
  one: '50px',
  two: '150px',
}
```

What i have tried so far.

Attempt 1:

```js
let t1 = []
Object.values(firstObj).forEach((index) => {
  t1.push(`${(parseInt(index.replace('px', '')) - 50).toString()}px`)
})
console.log(' t1', t1)
```

`t1 [ '50px', '150px' ]`

Attempt 2:

```js
let t2 = []
Object.entries(firstObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  t2.push({ [key]: `${value.replace('px', '') - 50}px` })
})
console.log(' t2', t2)
```

`t2 [ { one: '50px' }, { two: '150px' } ]`

Attempt 3:

```js
let t3 = []
Object.entries(firstObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  t3 = Object.create({})
  t3[key] = value.replace('px', '') - 50
})
console.log(' t3', t3)
```

`t3 { two: 150 }`

Attempt 4 Final:

```js
let temp = []
let t4
Object.entries(firstObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  temp.push({ [key]: `${value.replace('px', '') - 50}px` })
  t4 = Object.assign({}, ...temp)
})
console.log(' t4', t4)
```

`t5 { one: '50px', two: '150px' }`

This one does what i need to, but i think this code can look cleaner:

1. I have to use `temp` to store the values and then use them, would like to find out a way to not use `temp` variable
2. Any other tips on how can this be improved?
3. Would like to return new values to a variable straight away, but i have tried writing return but does not seem to work.

Idea of point `3` is to use function to return a value straight to object

```js
const obj = {
  secondObj: () => // return my function t4
}
```

How it should look under the hood:

```js
const obj = {
  secondObj: {
    one: '50px',
    two: '150px',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your main goal is to obtain `secondObj` from `firstObj`. You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to obtain a `[[key, value], ...]` pair array from your object, which you can then call [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on, which will allow you to transform each key, value pair into a new key-value pair. You can then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which will take these new `[[key, value], ...]` array and build an object for you:

```js
const firstObj = {
  one: '100px',
  two: '200px',
};

const secondObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(firstObj).map(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  value.replace(/\d+/, m => m - 50)
]));

console.log(secondObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values are always formatted like `${a_number}px`, then you could do this:

```
let firstObj = {one: '100px', two: '200px'}
let secondObj = {}

Object.entries(firstObj).forEach(
  ([k, v]) => secondObj[k] = Number.parseInt(v) - 50 + 'px'
)
```

Comment: I love this `Number.parseInt(v) - 50 + 'px'` because I'm using TS this does not give me errors now